# Convert Avro file to JSON with reader schema

Tags: java, json, avro

I would like to deserialize Avro data on the command line *with a reader schema that is different from the writer schema*. I can specify writer schema on serialization, but not during deserialization.

`record.json` (data file):

```
{"test1": 1, "test2": 2}
```

`writer.avsc` (writer schema):

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "pouac",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "test1",
            "type": "int"
        },
        {
            "name": "test2",
            "type": "int"
        }
    ]
}
```

`reader.avsc` (reader schema):

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "pouac",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "test2",
         "type": "int",
         "aliases": ["test1"]
    }]
}
```

Serializing data:

```
$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fromjson --schema-file writer.avsc record.json > record.avro
```

For deserializing data, I tried the following:

```
$ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson --schema-file reader.avsc record.avro
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: 'schema-file' is not a recognized option
...
```

I'm looking primarily for a command line instruction because I'm not so confortable writing Java code, but I'd be happy with Java code to compile myself. Actually, what I'm interested in is the exact deserialization result. (the more fundamental issue at stake is described in [this conversation](https://github.com/tebeka/fastavro/pull/113#pullrequestreview-77570134) on a fastavro PR that I opened to implement aliases)

Comment: What is your expected result from this? Given an input JSON file like `[{"test1": 1, "test2": 2}]` what is the output you expect?

Comment: In my opinion, we should obtain `[{"test2": 2}]` but the Avro spec is not very clear about this corner case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The avro-tools `tojson` target is only meant as a dump tool for translating a binary encoded Avro file to JSON. The schema always accompanies the records in the Avro file as outlined in the link below. As a result it cannot be overridden by avro-tools.

http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/#compare

I am not aware of a stand-alone tool that can be used to achieve what you want. I think you'll need to do some programming to achieve the desired results. Avro has many supported languages including Python but the capabilities across languages is not uniform. Java is in my experience the most advanced. As an example Python lacks the ability to specify a reader schema on the DataFileReader which would help achieve what you want:

https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/lang/py/src/avro/datafile.py#L224

The closest you can get in Python is the following;

```
import avro.schema as avsc
import avro.datafile as avdf
import avro.io as avio

reader_schema = avsc.parse(open("reader.avsc", "rb").read())

# need ability to inject reader schema as 3rd arg
with avdf.DataFileReader(open("record.avro", "rb"), avio.DatumReader()) as reader:
    for record in reader:
        print record
```

In terms of the schemas and the data you've outlined. The expected behaviour should be **undefined** and therefore emit an **error**.

This behaviour can be verified with the following Java code;

```
package ca.junctionbox.soavro;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidationException;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidationStrategy;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidator;
import org.apache.avro.SchemaValidatorBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static final String V1 = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"pouac\",\n" +
            "    \"fields\": [\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"test1\",\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"int\"\n" +
            "        },\n" +
            "        {\n" +
            "            \"name\": \"test2\",\n" +
            "            \"type\": \"int\"\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    ]\n" +
            "}";

    public static final String V2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"type\": \"record\",\n" +
            "    \"name\": \"pouac\",\n" +
            "    \"fields\": [{\n" +
            "        \"name\": \"test2\",\n" +
            "         \"type\": \"int\",\n" +
            "         \"aliases\": [\"test1\"]\n" +
            "    }]\n" +
            "}";

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SchemaValidator sv = new SchemaValidatorBuilder()
                .canBeReadStrategy()
                .validateAll();
        final Schema sv1 = new Schema.Parser().parse(V1);
        final Schema sv2 = new Schema.Parser().parse(V2);
        final ArrayList<Schema> existing = new ArrayList<>();
        existing.add(sv1);

        try {
            sv.validate(sv2, existing);
            System.out.println("Good to go!");
        } catch (SchemaValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This yields the following output:

```
org.apache.avro.SchemaValidationException: Unable to read schema: 
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "pouac",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "test2",
    "type" : "int",
    "aliases" : [ "test1" ]
  } ]
}
using schema:
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "pouac",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "test1",
    "type" : "int"
  }, {
    "name" : "test2",
    "type" : "int"
  } ]
}
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateMutualRead.canRead(ValidateMutualRead.java:70)
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateCanBeRead.validate(ValidateCanBeRead.java:39)
    at org.apache.avro.ValidateAll.validate(ValidateAll.java:51)
    at ca.junctionbox.soavro.Main.main(Main.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Aliases are typically used for backwards compatibility in schema evolution allowing mappings from disparate/legacy keys to a common key name. Given your writer schema doesn't treat the test1 and test2 fields as "optional" through the use of unions I can't see what scenario you'd want this transformation. If you want to "drop" the test1 field then it can be achieved by excluding it from the v2 schema specification. Any reader that can apply a reader scheme would then ignore test1 using the v2 schema definition.

To illustrate what I mean by evolution;

**v1 schema**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "pouac",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "test1",
        "type": "int"
    }]
}
```

**v2 schema**

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "pouac",
  "fields": [
    {
        "name": "test2",
        "type": "int",
        "aliases": ["test1"]
    }]
}
```

You could have terabytes of data in the v1 format and introduce the v2 format which renames the test1 field to test2. The alias would allow you to perform map-reduce jobs, Hive queries, etc on both v1 and v2 data without proactively rewriting all the old v1 data first. Note this assumes there is no change in type and the semantic meaning of the fields.

Comment: Exactly! Actually, what I am trying to do is to improve the fastavro Python implementation by introducing aliases :) Here is the PR: https://github.com/tebeka/fastavro/pull/113
On implementing this feature, I stumbled on this corner case of schema resolution (http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Schema+Resolution). I'd like to know how the Java reference implementation resolves it. (IMHO the reference Python implementation is terrible)
I guess I'll have to read the Java source code!

Comment: I've updated my response including Java code. I think you should reference the PR in your question. I'm not sure the subject actually reflects what you ultimately want to know which is "how does Avro resolve an alias".

Comment: I did reference the PR in my question, but maybe the wording was not explicit enough: I'll try to improve it. I guess I could've asked "how does the reference Avro implementation resolve an alias if the field is already present", but I'm more interested in the general solution, so I can debug other corner cases myself.
What is the stacktrace that you get with that error?

Comment: Updated to include output. Apologies did see the link I was just thinking it would be good to state upfront what you're working on. Suppose it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson` to see the help, what it tells is that you can use this command like:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson record.avro > tost.json
```

and this will output to the file:

```
{"test1":1,"test2":2}
```

Also you can call it with `--pretty` argumment:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar tojson --pretty record.avro > tost.json
```

and the output will be pretty:

```
{
  "test1" : 1,
  "test2" : 2
}
```

Comment: My question is specifically about how to deserialize with a reader schema different from the writer schema.